# bundle install can not be executed and causes error on rails production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, bundle

We use capistrano for rails deployment. Here is a strange error when running `bundle install` on production server.

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have added to the Gemfile:
* rails (= 3.1.3)
* mysql2 (>= 0.2.6)

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* rails (~> 3.1.3)
```

Gemfile on production server was manually changed and then, this error comes out. This is a new production server and we plan to run rails 3.1.3. We rebooted the linux server and it did not help. Is there way to fix the problem? thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you're using some deployment solution, like Capistrano. If this is the case, change the Gemfile on a development machine, run `bundle install`, commit everything into the repository and deploy again.

Don't ever change code manually on the server, it's gonna be bad for your karma.

**Edit:**

If you want to use some specific gems in production only, add them to production group.

```
# Gemfile
group :production do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

Comment: Will try it again. Did recommit and redeploy. But the problem was not solved. We don't use mysql on development and this is the only difference in gemfile.

Comment: looks good and will try. Is changing database.yml file OK? Our cap will copy gem file and database.yml. With this group, there is no need to copy the gemfile. Thanks.

Comment: Our deployment has some problem and there is no new deployment. I guess that's why the error keep coming up. Cap deploy has been mysterious for us.

Comment: It's a new machine, wipe it and start afresh, while you can :)

I had some problems with deployments, but they all were caused by me, not capistrano.

Comment: It seems the deploy rollback. Here is a error from deploy:  failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/byop/releases/20120301215910 && bundle install --gem
e --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 176.195.225.93. bundle install failed. There is not many resource available for cap deployment.

Comment: Did you clean that manual edit? I'm telling you, nuke the installation and start fresh.

Comment: For fresh, did you mean reinstall the passenger and all other? Or just wipe out the /var/www/ and recreate it again?

Comment: Yep, the `/var/www` (or whereever capistrano deploys your app).

Comment: Just wiped out byop. What's the rights for the byop for the group www-data and the user for the deploy? Currently for dir byop, we assign the user create and delete, for file it is read and write. For group www-data, it is access files on dir byop and read-only for the files. thanks.